# backing bean is not called from jsp in jssf 1.2

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am using a javascript method to call a backing bean method from a jsp page in jsf 1.2.The javascript method is  firing but the backing bean is not called from the jsp page .I am posting what i have done here

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="panelGroup" id="grpMemDep"> 
                                            <h:selectOneMenu id="memDepCode" styleClass="inputfont" onchange="getMemberDepInfo();">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="----SELECT----" itemValue="0"/>
                                                    <f:selectItems id="selectItems32"
                                                        value="#{searchUserProfileBean.memberDependentList}" />
                                                </h:selectOneMenu>

                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                      <hx:commandExButton type="submit" value="submit"
                                                styleClass="commandExButton"
                                                id="getAllMemberDepInformation" action="#{pc_userManagementProfile.doGetAllMemDepInfoAction}" >
                                                <hx:behavior event="onclick" id="behavior21" behaviorAction="get"></hx:behavior>
                                            </hx:commandExButton>
```

This is the javascript code

```
function getMemberDepInfo(){

//alert(document.getElementById('vwmyUserProfile:myUserProfileForm:getAllMemberDepInformation').value);
document.getElementById('vwmyUserProfile:myUserProfileForm:getAllMemberDepInformation').click();
```

}

the backing bean method

```
public String doGetAllMemDepInfoAction(){

System.out.println("coms in the method");

    System.out.println("Information :"+getMemDepCode().getValue().toString().trim());


    return "";
}
```

This is entry in the faces-config

```
<managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>pc_userManagementProfile</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>pagecode.com.metlife.eservice.member.UserManagementProfile</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

The problem is that the submit button is not working ,I am new to JSF please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any speical reason to use JS you can use  `valueChangeListener

A method binding to a method that responds to value changes`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi we are using hidden button to call the backing bean thats why the process i  have followed

Comment: Do you mean onChange you are submitting the form ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi  i  want  to call the  backing bean onchange

Comment: That you can done by `valueChangeListener` attribute of `<h:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi can you edit my code please i am new to jsf

Comment: You can use like this `<h:selectOneMenu id="memDepCode" styleClass="inputfont" valueChangeListener ="#{searchUserProfileBean.doGetAllMemDepInfoAction()}">`